# Ivy: using a common library for unit tests while avoiding circular dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, ivy, circular-dependency

I have a few Ivy projects - let's call them `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, that need a common base for unit tests. In order to reuse code I created a separate project `Z` just to hold this unit test common foundation and added it as a dependency to the various Ivy projects (I'm using JUnit by the way).

The problem is: project `Z` depends on some classes from the projects `A` and `B`. Result: circular dependency. `Z` depends on `A` and `B` for this "unit test foundation", and `A` and `B` depend on `Z` for the unit tests.

I understand circular dependency is undesirable. I get a warning every time I compile the code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, but also quite difficult.

Move the things that depends on A or B out of Z and into A and B.

When this doesn't work move the things in A and B that Z depends on into Z.

Repeat.

You may discover that you have classes with mixed responsibilities that will need to be split apart so that concerns that ought to live in A/B/Z can be separated.

Tools exist that can help you visualise the dependencies, which might help.